# Code for "simple_list_item_2"?

Tags: android

Been working on an android application with a custom listview. I recently had to change to a cursor to accomplish what I wanted to do.

As a result, I ended up making use of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` because it worked how I wanted. Problem is that I would like to change a few properties such as font color and edit my cell as I see fit.

Question is, Can I find the code for simple_list_item_2 somewhere and edit it as my own, and call it instead of simple_list_item_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the code for this component by searching for `simple_list_item_2.xml` in the Android Open Source Project's frameworks. For example, it's available [here in the GitHub mirror of the official repository](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml).

Answer (score 5):

easy to get it. If you use Android Studio, you can put your cursor on `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` and press Ctrl + B or F4 to get it.

if I don't make a mistake, F4 similar to F3 on Eclipse!

**UPDATE 1**

on Android Studio, you also get it by right click on it and Go To >> Declaration

**UPDATE 2**

on Android Studio, you also get it by hold controll and click on simple_list_item_2.

If you use Android Studio on MacOS, let hold CMD instead

Comment: `F4` didn't work for me, but `Ctrl+B` did. Thank you - this is one to remember! :-)

Comment: It based on your settings Keymap at: Files -> Settings -> Keymap. If you use default settings `F4` will work